# Is there any way i can input a Date of class Date and then use it in other class as an integer?

Tags: java

I have a problem with Dates and Calendars in Java.Specifically i have to get a user's input which is an object of class Date and then to use that object as an integer in another class..I hava a package .util that does all of scanning and reading ...but i dont know how to use it.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code that you've written? It would help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Date dDate  = sir.readDate("Enter Vehicle's Rental Date (dd/mm/yyyy) : ");
   Date returnDate = sir.readDate("Enter Vehicle's Return Date (dd/mm/yyyy) : ");
   corp.addNewRental(cl, vcles, dDate, returnDate));

Comment: public void  addNewRental(Clients c , Vehicles v, Date dd, Date rd ) {
  if(c != null && v != null) {
   if(v.getNumOfRentals() < v.getNumOfTotalRentals()) {
    
    // Calendar Object
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    StandardInputRead sir = new StandardInputRead();
    
    
    // Date object
    Date dDate = new Date();
    // Date Object
    dd = dDate.getDate();
    
    cal.add(dd, rd);
          Date retDate = cal.getTime();
          
          //Create the Lending Object
          Rentals r = new Rentals(c, v, dDate , retDate);

Answer (score 0):

A date is not an integer, but you can use the method [`getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) on the `Date` object to get:

> ... the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Note that this value is returned as **long**, not as int.

The code can be something similar to:

```
Date myDate = ...             // Setting date to  Wednesday 10 April 2019 15:30:00

long myDateAsLong = myDate.getTime();  // Is 1554910200000
```